# Let's let this tag [decay]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

There's a [decay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/decay) tag on SO.

It doesn't have a tag-wiki and there are 35 questions with this tag on SO. It has been mainly used for 1) questions related to "array-to-pointer-conversion" in C and C++ languages 2) questions on "decay functions" in Python, MySQL, R etc. Note that there are *completely* different usages/meanings.

Considering it has no tag-wiki and its ambiguous usage and that there are only 35 questions tagged it, it appears to be a candidate for deletion. Do we need this tag?

(The other option is to "define" the tag clearly with a wiki if this is deemed necessary).

Comment: Proposed title: "Let it [decay] to nothing".

Comment: [decay] needs a short *half-life*?

Comment: @Paulie_D Should this be burninated, we should update when there are 18 left, 9, 5, 3, 2, 1, 0 left.

Comment: @Paulie_D [decay] has a short half-life ;)

Comment: What even is a "decay function"? Is it just a mathematical function that decreases towards 0? Googling only turns up "exponential decay." And if that's what it means, why isn't it just called exponential decay? And exponential decay isn't a programming topic and is extremely unlikely to be particularly informative about what expertise you need to answer the question.

Comment: I like the Halloween feel to this tag

Comment: @jpmc26 A decay function is a function describing decay. There are different kinds of decay functions, exponential decay is a common (and simple) one, but there's also log decay and Gaussian decay (and there might be even more that I'm not aware of). These are all loosely related, they might be too niche to deserve their own tag, but too dissimilar to fit under one _decay-function_ tag.

Comment: I spent the last 8 days burninating the tag slooowly, so that we can get the decay tag to decay https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxUpL.png

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I got the burnination criteria from [meta Stack Overflow.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071/3551604) Please tell me if I messed up.

1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?
   No. The OP answers that - questions tagged with [decay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/decay) are about different things across different languages that aren't all the same.
2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?
   Not as standalone topic. Decay functions of a programming language are on topic, "'array-to-pointer-conversion' in C and C++" is also on-topic but lumping them together doesn't work.
3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?
   If new tags were created for decay functions and array-to-pointer-conversion, probably, but as is, there's little to extract from it.
4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?
   Obviously not as demonstrated by OP.

I would say that now is time for burning with a generous side of retagging.